# MySQL query took extremely long time to finish and it was in 'Sending data' state

Tags: mysql

This query took extremly long time and it never seemed to finish.

Below is the query:

```
INSERT INTO `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`

    SELECT a.* 
    FROM `zhihu_answer_meta` a 
    LEFT JOIN `zhihu_answer_meta_staging` b 
            ON a.answer_id   = b.answer_id 
           AND a.insert_time = b.insert_time 
    WHERE b.answer_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

    SELECT * 
    FROM `zhihu_answer_meta_staging`
```

The row numbers of these tables are:

```
zhihu_answer_meta_staging: 1074588
zhihu_answer_meta: 2315697
zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile: 0  this table is a newly created table for inserting data into.
```

Besides, both of three tables' structure is the same.

```
CREATE TABLE `zhihu_answer_meta` (
  `answer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `author_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reward_member_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `voteup_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_advertiser` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_url_token` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_org` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `insert_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `badge_num` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reward_total_money` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `can_comment` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `answer_index` (`answer_id`,`insert_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Appretiate if anyone can give some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create indexes suitable for your query. Does `(answer_id, insert_time)` fields combination must be unique in your tables (or in `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile` table at least)?

Comment: @Akina yes the combination of answer_id and insert_time is unique. I already created that index for the combination

Comment: Edit your question text and insert new DDL. *both of two tables' structure is the same* There is 3 tables mentioned in your question - destination + 2 source.

Comment: @Akina updated the question. actually both of the 3 tables structure are the same.

Comment: Your table has the only index, it is UNIQUE, and ENGINE=InnoDB. So this index is clustered. So it acts as a primary key. So you may make it primary freely.

Comment: OK, I made it as primary key.

Comment: It is a decoration and makes no sense in that case, of course. But PK existence is a good practice.

Comment: `insert_time` is NULLable, hence the `UNIQUE` will not be promoted to `PRIMARY`.  If it is never `NULL`, say `NOT NULL`.

Comment: What are the keys in `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`?

Comment: @Akina - Your comment missed the point that `insert_time` is `NULLable`, hence it cannot be clustered.

Comment: @Rick James Thanks for your comment, in fact, there is not Null in insert_time, I should set it to `NOT NULL`. zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile a clone table of zhihu_answer_meta, so the keys are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the combination of `answer_id` and `insert_time` is unique. I already created that index for the combination

1. Create this UNIQUE index on destination table (`zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`).
2. Perform the action you need with 2 separate queries:

```sql
-- TRUNCATE `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`;
INSERT INTO `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`
    SELECT * FROM `zhihu_answer_meta_staging`;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `zhihu_answer_meta_reconcile`
    SELECT * FROM `zhihu_answer_meta`;
```

These queries may be combined into one line. While using from some code check that the inserting function/method allows multi-query in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. After added UNIQUE index, it became much faster. These two seperate queries are faster than my insert SQL above? I didn't understand, could you tell me more ?  Thanks.

Comment: @DennisLi No query and JOIN, no UNION and possible materialization, and unique condition check is performed immediately during insert (on the stage of index update, it seems). A lot of operations not needed ejected, and no new operations added. It have no chance not to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you are joining a.answer_id to b.answer_id and you are giving the clause where b.answer_id is null the joining condition over here will work as a cross apply and will multiply the records. You should change the condition in your where clause.

Comment: *You should change the condition in your where clause.* Changing condition will change the logic. It is not applicable. *will work as a cross apply and will multiply the records* No. It can be null only when no matched record in right table (see - this field can be included into PK, so it cannot be null). So only one matched record possible.